# Xamarin.Forms Page bottom to top animation

Tags: c#, xaml, animation, xamarin.forms, transition

When I set the animation to true in the PushAsync method, the page transition happens is left to right but I would like to have a bottom to top transition how the settings page appears in the iOS Youtube app. Could anyone help me how to achieve this with Xamarin.Forms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To present a page from bottom to top, you should [modal pages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/modal#performing-navigation):

```
async void OnNextPageButtonClicked (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  // Page appearance animated
  await Navigation.PushModalAsync (new DetailPage (), true);
}

async void OnDismissButtonClicked (object sender, EventArgs args)
{
  // Page appearance animated
  await Navigation.PopModalAsync (true);
}
```

[Navigation pages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/hierarchical) is different from it.

You can read the document for more information.